# Example for a manifold whose tangent bundle is diffeomorphic to a product but not trivial

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

It is stated [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220044/any-example-of-manifold-without-global-trivialization-of-tangent-bundle) that:

For $F:TM→M×R^n$ to be a global trivialization, we need not just that $F$ is a diffeomorphism, but that $F$ preserves all of this structure. In particular, when restricted to a single tangent space, $F$ must be an isomorphism. This is much stronger than simply requiring $F$ be a diffeomorphism between $TM$ and $M×R^n$.

I would like to see an example when the first condition holds while the second fails. That is, to find a manifold $M$ which admits a diffeomorphism $F$ but has a nontrivial tangent bundle.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that this is much stronger?

Comment: There are two questions you could be asking here, namely 1) exhibit a particular $F$ which is a diffeomorphism but not a trivialization of the tangent bundle or 2) exhibit an $M$ which admits a diffeomorphism $F$ but has a nontrivial tangent bundle. The first is not hard (there's an easy example where $M = \mathbb{R}^n$) but the second I don't know an example of off the top of my head.

Comment: You are right. I meant the second option. I have edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: There is no need to move this question to MO, as it is already there! http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58793/nontrivial-tangent-bundle-that-is-diffeomorphic-to-the-trivial-bundle ç

Comment: By the way, it is not my immense memory that got the to that question: I simply googled "site:mathoverflow.net tangent bundle diffeomorphic".